# How to tetsing completely fill the coverage of my method with java and Junit?

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, sonarqube

I have a Java service that consults a DB and returns a list, into my service I call the method **validacionCampos()** of my Util class, this class validates if a field of the list of my service  has a null value or is 0 the value is set 0.000

My goal is to have a test case that covers all the service method and validations of the util class.
I made a test clase but it doesn't work at all because the sonarqube tool says that it is not fully covered and points to the **if** lines of the util class, I made two methods, one setting the null value and another method for the value 0 , but I think it's wrong or does nothing

anyone can help me please, How is the testcase done so that it enters the service and the useful class and the coverage is fully?

ServiceImpl Class

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<?> consultarReportes(Integer fechaInicio, Integer fechaFin) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    List<EntityDa> consultarReporte = new ArrayList<EntityDa>();
    try {
        consultarReporte = bitacoraRepository
                .consultarBitacoras(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
        reporteUtil.validacionCampos(consultarReporte);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for Entity Data");
        response.put("success", false);
        response.put("error", e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    response.put("success", true);
    response.put("data", consultarReporte);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Util class

```
private static final String DECIMAL = "0.0000";

        public List<EntityDa> validacionCampos(List<EntityDa> lista) {
        for (EntityDa details : lista) {
            if (details.getRango() == null || details.getRango().equals("0")) {
                details.setRango(DECIMAL);
            }
            if (details.getPrima() == null || details.getPrima().equals("0")) {
                details.setPrima(DECIMAL);
            }
        }
        return lista;
        }
```

Test class

```
@Mock
BitacoraRepository bitacoraRepository;

@Test
void testExitoValidaNullos() throws Exception {
    EntityDa entity = new EntityDa();
    entity.setRango(null);
    entity.setPrima(null);
    
    List<EntityDa> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(entity);
    when(bitacoraRepository.consultarBitacoras("20220112", "20220112")).thenReturn(list);
}

@Test
void testExitoValidaVacios() throws Exception {
    EntityDa entity = new EntityDa();
    entity.setRango("0");
    entity.setPrima("0");
    
    List<EntityDa> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(entity);
    when(bitacoraRepository.consultarBitacoras("20220112", "20220112")).thenReturn(list);
}
```

UPDATE

I IMPLEMENTED IT AS YOUR EXAMPLE AND IT STAYED LIKE THIS BECAUSE THE IDE ADDED A CAST TO **ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>** because my service is declarated  ResponseEntity<?>

```
@Test
    public void testExitoValidaNullos() throws Exception {
        // Given a repository containing an entity with "rango" and "prima" set to null
        EntityDa entity = new EntityDa();
        entity.setRango(null);
        entity.setPrima(null);

        List<EntityDa> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(entity);
        when(bitacoraRepository.consultarBitacoras("20220112", "20220112")).thenReturn(list);

        // When consultarReportes is called
        ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> response = (ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> serviceImpl.consultarReportes("20220112", "20220112");


        // Then the returned entity should have "rango" and "prima" set to "0.0000"
        EntityDa returnedEntity = ((List<EntityDa>) response.getBody().get("data")).get(0);
        assertEquals("0.0000", returnedEntity.getRango());
        assertEquals("0.0000", returnedEntity.getPrima());
    }
```

I ran the test and it sends this:

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <0.0000> but was: <41831.3>

apparently it is not taking the settings to null

**UPDATE**

TESTING THE UTIL CLASS DIRECTLY I GET THE ERROR NullPointerException in the line **claseUtil.validacionCampos(list);**

```
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc
    @SpringBootTest
    public class ClaseTest {
    
    @Autowired
    ClaseUtil claseUtil;
    
    
    @Test
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        EntityDa entity = new EntityDa();
        entity.setRango(null);
        entity.setPrima(null);

        List<EntityDa> list = new ArrayList<EntityDa>();
        list.add(entity);

        claseUtil.validacionCampos(list);

    }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like these tests don't execute `consultarReportes` at all. They only  set up the mock and then don't do anything that uses it.

Comment: @TimMoore How should the test case be for that method to be executed, can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube reports no coverage for those lines because these tests do not actually execute this code. They perform some setup, but do not call any methods on `ServiceImpl`.

It's useful to think of tests as having three sections, usually called **given**, **when**, and **then**:

- **Given** represents the context or environment of the test case
- **When** describes the action that is taken - the operation that is being tested
- **Then** describes the expected or intended outcome

It might be helpful to use written language to write out the requirements in this format, and then translate the written requirements to code.

For example, I might write the requirements for these test cases (in English):

- **Given** a repository containing an entity with a "rango" of `null` or "0",
- **When** `consultarReportes` is called,
- **Then** the returned entity should have "rango" set to "0.0000"

And:

- **Given** a repository containing an entity with a "prima" of `null` or "0",
- **When** `consultarReportes` is called,
- **Then** the returned entity should have "prima" set to "0.0000"

In terms of code:

- **Given** often translates to setting up data and sometimes mocks.
- **When** is a call to the method under test.
- **Then** is usually an assertion about the return value, or some other state affected by the method. It can also be verifications of methods called on mock objects, particularly when you are testing a method with no return value that only performs side effects.

In this case, the tests might look like this:

```
@Test
public void testExitoValidaNullos() throws Exception {
    // Given a repository containing an entity with "rango" and "prima" set to null
    EntityDa entity = new EntityDa();
    entity.setRango(null);
    entity.setPrima(null);

    List<EntityDa> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(entity);
    BitacoraRepository bitacoraRepository = mock(BitacoraRepository.class);
    when(bitacoraRepository.consultarBitacoras("20220112", "20220112")).thenReturn(list);

    // When consultarReportes is called
    ServiceImpl serviceImpl = new ServiceImpl(bitacoraRepository);
    ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> response = serviceImpl.consultarReportes("20220112", "20220112");

    // Then the returned entity should have "rango" and "prima" set to "0.0000"
    EntityDa returnedEntity = ((List<EntityDa>) response.getBody().get("data")).get(0);
    assertEquals("0.0000", returnedEntity.getRango());
    assertEquals("0.0000", returnedEntity.getPrima());
}
```

The change to testExitoValidaVacios would be similar.

(I made a few other changes to the supplied code to allow it to compile.)

To fully cover all possibilities, you would also want to write test cases for when these fields are set to other values. You may also want to test the exception handler by stubbing `bitacoraRepository.consultarBitacoras` to throw an exception.

Note that it would probably be simpler to test these cases against the `Util` class directly. This would require much less setup (no need for mocks) and would not require unpacking the entity from the response.

Comment: thanks a lot, This is clearer to me from the tests

Comment: I already implemented it but i had to change this -- >   ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> response   to this -- >  ResponseEntity<?> because this is how my service is declared, but when making that change it marks an error on the line get("data")).get(0);,  eclipse says Add cast to response.getBody(), but the test doesn't work that way

Comment: I made an update on my question

Comment: Are you injecting the mocked repository into the service?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean but that's how I put it
 @ Mock
BitacoraRepository bitacoraRepository;  and @ Autowired ClassServiceImpl serviceImpl;

Comment: Try changing `@Autowired` to `@InjectMocks`. The value "41831.3" doesn't appear anywhere in the test, so `serviceImpl` must be using the real repository implementation instead of the mocked one.

Comment: I tried like this:   @InjectMocks ClassServiceImpl serviceImpl; but the test throws  java.lang.NullPointerException, How do I get the service to use the mock repository?

Comment: the error of  java.lang.NullPointerException is in line --- > EntityDa returnedEntity = ((List<EntityDa>) response.getBody().get("data")).get(0);   and my TestClass is  annoted with  @ AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ SpringBootTest
class  TestCases {}

Comment: I've updated the answer to be more self-contained. It no longer relies on instance variables, annotations, or a custom JUnit runner. It assumes that `ServiceImpl` has a constructor that accepts an instance of `BitacoraRepository`, which I  would recommend. The test passes in my copy of the code.

Comment: As I mentioned above, you might find it simpler to test the `Util` class, directly, which you can do without using Mockito. It's probably also worth reviewing the Mockito documentation to reinforce your understanding of how to set it up and work  with it.

Comment: thanks, I try to test the util class directly and got the error NullPointerException, I update the question to show you how i did it

Comment: Try creating the class directly in the test, like in my last update to the answer. All of the annotation-based wiring can be hard to debug.

Comment: As a general tip, if you’re having a hard time getting something complicated to work, try simplifying until you can get it working, then build the complexity up from the simple, working components.